# Можно ли использовать свой шейдер в 2D рендерере в unity?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, hlsl

У меня есть шейдер цветовой палитры, который работает в дефолтном пайплайне и в forward renderer(как renderer feature), но я хочу использовать его с 2D освещением, только не нахожу такой возможности.

Пробовал использовать шейдер граф но что-то пошло не так(материал применяется к спрайту уровня):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно должно выглядеть так, только на спрайте не будет плавного градиента, а только 64 цвета из палитры[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Шейдерграф должен работать в Universal Render Pipeline **UPR** 2) Материал не подбрасывает монеток к чему ему применяться, он на том на что вы его наложили 3) Когда пишешь, что `что-то пошло не так, было бы совсем не странно, если бы описал, а как должно быть.

Comment: @Yaroslav спрайт уровня должен отрисовываться не этим непонятным серым, а цветами из палитры(которые возвращаются из custom function), при этом освещение на этом спрайте тоже должно отрисовываться с палитрой(добавил примерное изображение)